# strange css error on focus

Tags: html, css

I found this example since this style in good so i inserted in my project

following example is search box in `html` & `css`

### ERROR only in chrome, safari

### works good in firefox

when i click(focus) on search box it works as styled **but a blue border line appear** when clicked **i don't want the blue border** when i click on input box i tried remove shadow still no success

```css
            .wrap{position: absolute;
text-align: center;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(0%,-50%);
-moz-transform: translate(0%,-50%);
transform: translate(0%,-50%);}
            
          .se {
margin-left:50px;
}


#search input[type="text"] {
    background: url(search-white.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #444;
    border: 0 none;
    font: bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    color: #d7d7d7;
    width:150px;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    }

#search input[type="text"]:focus {
    background: url(search-dark.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #fcfcfc;
    color: #6a6f75;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
```

```html
 <div class="wrap se">
                            <form method="get" action="/search" id="search">
                                <input name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search..." />
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `outline: none` on the input to remove chrome's input highlighting

```
#search input[type="text"]{
   outline: none;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldkmvrqn/)

Comment: outline on `#search input[type="text"]:focus` or `#search input[type="text"]`